# discord.js DiscordApi: missing permissions

Tags: discord.js

im trying to make a change nickname command

```js
if(isValidCommand(message, "changenick")){
        try {
           if (mention == null){return message.reply("changenick who? dumb dumb")}
           nickname = message.content.slice(8 + mention);
           let member = message.mentions.members.first();
           member = await member.setNickname(nickname);
        }
        catch (e) {console.error(e);
        return message.channel.send("something went wrong!");}
           }
```

but i get the error DiscordAPIerror: missing permissions even when trying it in my own server

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

1. Make sure the bot itself has the MANAGE_NICKNAMES permission.
2. A user can only change the nickname of a person below them in the role hierarchy, this applies to bots as well.

Comment: my bot has administrator permission and everysingle permission of my discord server but i doesn't work